# In JSP, How to display the selected value in a dropdown onto <c:out>

Tags: jsp

In my JSP page, I am having a dropdown which contains two values. At any point in time, either one will always be selected. I want to print this selected value in the same JSP page through a c:out but I am not able to do so. Request help. Thanks.

My code is as follows,

```
<li class="Selectbox">

<select id="slbTypeId" name = "slbTypeName" onChange="Slb.onChangeType();" 
style="width: 200px; height: 23px; margin-left: 40px; margin-bottom: 20px;" > 

<c:forEach items="${TYPES}" var="slbType">
<option value="slbType" tempCode="${slbType}">
<spring:message code="label.menu.${slbType}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>                                
</li>
```

Comment: It seems you'rre using spring MVC. Why don't you use [the spring form tag library](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-form.tld)?

Comment: How to do that? I am not getting it.

Comment: spring MVC has a tag library dedicated to form components. Why don't you use it, just like you're using the spring library to display i18ned messages? I don't understand what you don't get. There's nothing to get. It's just a question.